# Parent Wrapper Fragment handling two OnItemClick events

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-tabs, onitemclicklistener

I have created a Tab FragmentActivity class that manages 4 tabs.

Tab one contains a wrapper Fragment to act as a parent to:

**1) A ListFragment** (Displaying categories) - When an item in the list is clicked the sublist of item is displayed (# 2 below) in the same tab by calling list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() in the wrapper fragment and using:

```
getChildFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.container, details)
      .addToBackStack(null)
      .commit();
```

Clicking on the first list and having the second displayed is no problem works great.  Clicking on the second list to have the detail displayed... that is where I am having issues.

**2) A List Fragment (Displaying the sublist)** -- I am trying to implement the second setOnItemClickListener in the wrapper to listen for the click on this sub list.  I cant figure out how to implement this.

**3) A Fragment (Displaying the detail of the item selected in 2 above)**

```
public class CategoryListWrapperFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String EXTRA_ITEM_ID_STRING = "com.f.lite.item_selected_from_list_id";

private String mPassId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DealListFragment deallist = new DealListFragment();

    deallist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {  
            Log.d("Wrapper", "Inside deallist on click listner");
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(EXTRA_ITEM_ID_STRING, mPassId);           

                // Create details fragment based on clicked item's position
                DealFragment details = new DealFragment();
                details.setArguments(args);

                getChildFragmentManager()
                  .beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.container, details)
                  .addToBackStack(null)
                  .commit();
        }
    });      


    CategoryListFragment list = new CategoryListFragment();

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {  

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(EXTRA_ITEM_ID_STRING, mPassId);           

                    DListFragment sublist = new DListFragment();
                sublist.setArguments(args);

                getChildFragmentManager()
                  .beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.container, sublist)
                  .addToBackStack(null)
                  .commit();
        }
    });
    getChildFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container, list)
    .commit();   
}

public void setPassId(String passIn) {
    mPassId = passIn;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // There has to be a view with id `container` inside `wrapper.xml`
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.wrapper, container, false);
}
}

enter code here
public class CategoryListFragment extends ListFragment {

private OnItemClickListener listener;
private ArrayList<Category> mCategory;
ImageView mCategoryImageView;

@Override
public void onAttach (Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.category_title);
    mCategory = CategoryLab.get(getActivity()).getCategory();   

    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(mCategory);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}   

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Category c = ((CategoryAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);        

    CategoryListWrapperFragment parent = (CategoryListWrapperFragment)getParentFragment();
    parent.setPassId(c.getmCategory());

    if(listener != null) {
        listener.onItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      }

}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener l) {
    this.listener = l;
}
```

....

public class DListFragment extends ListFragment {

```
private ArrayList<Deal> mDeals;

private OnItemClickListener listener;
private String mCategoryID;



@Override
public void onAttach (Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         

    mCategoryID = (String)getArguments().getString(CategoryListWrapperFragment.EXTRA_ITEM_ID_STRING);
    mDeals = DealLab.get(getActivity()).getDeals(mCategoryID);      

    getActivity().setTitle(mCategoryID);

    DealAdapter adapter = new DealAdapter(mDeals);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Deal d = ((DealAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

    CategoryListWrapperFragment parent = (CategoryListWrapperFragment)getParentFragment();
    parent.setPassId(Long.toString(d.getmId()));

    if(listener != null) {
        listener.onItemClick(l, v, position, id);
      }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mDeals = DealLab.get(getActivity()).getDeals(mCategoryID);          

    DealAdapter adapter = new DealAdapter(mDeals);
    setListAdapter(adapter);        
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener l) {
    this.listener = l;
}
```

}
......

Comment: I am sure this is not the best solution but it works.  I created a function in the wrapper to set the second onListItemClick listener and then call that function from the child fragment onCreate.  It works fine but there is likely a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure this is not the best solution but it works. I created a function in the wrapper to set the second onListItemClick listener and then call that function from the child fragment onCreate. It works fine but there is likely a cleaner way to do this.